# R : for grouped observations, checking if their buffers intersect (finding duplicates)

Tags: r, duplicates, buffer

I have a dataframe with lots of observations, and I want to remove duplicates.
I have a *sf* variable *geometry* with coordinates, that I used to create buffers like this :

```
data$geometry = st_transform(data$geometry, 3857)
data$polygons = st_buffer(data$geometry, 500)
```

To check for duplicates, first, I run this code (from the package *janitor*) :

```
data <- get_dupes(data, date, name)
```

Which isolates the observations with duplicates on *date* and *name*.

Then, I want to group my observations by this two variables (*date* and *name*), and then ask if within each group the polygons intersect (variable *polygons*). If true, I want a new variable *duplicate* to indicate 1. If false (no intersection), I want *duplicate* = 0.

I already tried to run this code :

```
data$intersect <- st_intersects(data$polygons, sparse = TRUE)
```

But it only returns for each observation a list of the observations' ID whose buffer intersect with, and I don't know how to use it to have the result I want above (with the creation of a new variable *duplicate*).

I don't know if what I want is understandable. Thank you for your help.